# Publish Application on appstore ERROR ITMS 90035 Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path

Tags: xcode, app-store, publish, archive, ipa

This error make me crazy i checked many times the signature is ok, clean project , deleted derived data, searched a lot but still getting this error :

ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The file at path [أسئلة ثقافة عامة.app/أسئلة ثقافة عامة] is not properly signed. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct, choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please consult [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html%22)

Other application i publish without problem the application on the appstore with the same account but this application give me everytime this error

Answer (score 0):

I passed days on this problem, tried lot of thing, what worked for me it's because the name of the application contains arabic caracters :( on xcode 10 i publish without any problem the app name was full arabic caracters
several years ago never got problem like this